# IndexError: too many indices for array for scikit-learn

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

When I run

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
estimate_bandwidth(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[..]/anaconda2/envs/reifen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py", line 72, in estimate_bandwidth
    d, _ = nbrs.kneighbors(X[batch, :], return_distance=True)
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I understand that the dimensionality of the array is not correct - but I am not sure what I did wrong here - the code isn't that long. Can estimate_bandwidth only be used with data that is multivariate?

Comment: You should read the documentation - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.estimate_bandwidth.html

Comment: @Craicerjack: I did, but didn't read anything about this. However reading again, I gathered that for the univariate case I need to use `.reshape((6, 1))` after the array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu should do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

d = estimate_bandwidth(array.reshape(len(array),1))
```

Comment: Although this is exactly what I just commented ;-) - it *is* the correct solution.

Comment: Yeah. probably :-). Happens.